# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Finding Max Element

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

Whenever I am trying to run this code, it gives me out of bound exception. Can anyone point me out what's wrong with it.

```
package com.programs.interview;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindMaxNumInArray {

public static void main (String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter the size of the array: "); 
    int arraySize = scan.nextInt(); 
    int[] myArray = new int[arraySize]; 
    System.out.print("Enter the " + arraySize + " values of the array: "); 
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        myArray[i] = scan.nextInt(); 
    for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) 
        System.out.println(myArray[j]); 
    System.out.println("In the array entered, the larget value is "+ maximum(myArray,arraySize) + "."); 
} 

public static int maximum(int[] arr, int Arraylength){
    int tmp;
    if (Arraylength == 0)
        return arr[Arraylength];
    tmp = maximum(arr, Arraylength -1);
    if (arr[Arraylength] > tmp)
        return arr[Arraylength];
    return tmp;
  }
}
```

**Output**

> Enter the size of the array: 5 Enter the 5 values of the array: 1 2 3
>   4 5 1 2 3 4 5 Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at
>   com.programs.interview.FindMaxNumInArray.maximum(FindMaxNumInArray.java:26)
>   at
>   com.programs.interview.FindMaxNumInArray.main(FindMaxNumInArray.java:17)

Comment: The Console Gives me this out put:
Enter the size of the array: 5
Enter the 5 values of the array: 1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at com.programs.interview.FindMaxNumInArray.maximum(FindMaxNumInArray.java:26)
 at com.programs.interview.FindMaxNumInArray.main(FindMaxNumInArray.java:17)

Comment: Yes, because an array with 5 elements does not have a element index [5]. Only 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? Using a loop would be simpler, and faster.

Comment: So ...? I mean is there problem in initializing the array with 5 ?

Comment: Actually m new in programming, and i was interviewed with recursive method.

Comment: Note that in Java, unlike C/C++, an array is an object, and it's unnecessary to pass in the array length unless you're using a recursive algorithm. In this case, iteration is faster and easier to understand than recursion, and you can eliminate this likely source of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if (arr[Arraylength] > tmp)
```

Valid array indexes go from `0` to `length-1` inclusive. `array[array.length]` is *always* invalid, and on the initial call, `ArrayLength` is equal to `arr.length`.

It's not clear why you're using recursion at all, to be honest. An iterative solution would be much simpler - but you'll need to work out what you want to do if the array is empty.

EDIT: If you really want how I would write the recursive form, it would be something like this:

```
/** Returns the maximum value in the array. */
private static int maximum(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        // You need to decide what to do here... throw an exception,
        // return some constant, whatever.
    }
    // Okay, so the length will definitely be at least 1...
    return maximumRecursive(array, array.length);
}

/** Returns the maximum value in array in the range [0, upperBoundExclusive) */
private static int maximumRecursive(int[] array, int upperBoundExclusive) {
    // We know that upperBoundExclusive cannot be lower than 1, due to the
    // way that this is called. You could add a precondition if you really
    // wanted.
    if (upperBoundExclusive == 1) {
        return array[0];
    }
    int earlierMax = maximumRecursive(array, upperBoundExclusive - 1);
    int topValue = array[upperBoundExclusive - 1];
    return Math.max(topValue, earlierMax);

    // Or if you don't want to use Math.max
    // return earlierMax > topValue ? earlierMax : topValue;
}
```

Comment: You mean this would help :
  public static int maximum(int[] arr, int Arraylength){
  int tmp;
        if (Arraylength == 0)
            return arr[Arraylength];
        tmp = maximum(arr, Arraylength-1);
        if (arr[Arraylength-1] > tmp)
            return arr[Arraylength];
        return tmp;
 }

Comment: @AliAnsari: No, that will still fail - you're still returning `arr[Arraylength]`, and if the array is empty then you're still going to try to take the first element from it. Again, you really need to decide what you want to do if the length of the array is 0.

Comment: Thnx Alot: it worked now:
 public static int maximum(int[] arr, int Arraylength){
  int tmp;
        if (Arraylength == 0)
            return arr[Arraylength];
        tmp = maximum(arr, Arraylength-1);
        if (arr[Arraylength-1] > tmp)
            return arr[Arraylength-1];
        return tmp;
 }

Comment: @AliAnsari: Well that's *still* not going to work if the array is empty, but other than that it's okay. It's not how I would write the code, mind you - I'd use iteration rather than recursion.

Comment: M also convenient with iterative solution, but my need was recursive. Kindly , can u re-write it as if you will have to write it. I need to compare that one with mine to clear that where am i mistaken.

Comment: @AliAnsari: Your mistake is not noticing that I've said *three times* that you need to work out what you want the answer to be if the array is empty. There are various approaches you could take (MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, 0, throw an exception...) but you really need to decide what to do.

Comment: Thats my actuall answer that i needed. Thnx

Comment: @AliAnsari: I've added how I would write the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can't access

```
arr[Arraylength]
```

the last element would be at

```
arr[Arraylength -1]
```

for example if you have

```
int arr[] = new int[5];
```

then the elements would be at `4`, because index starts from `0`

```
arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]
```

Comment: Thnx alot for explaining

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the following piece of code:

```
if (arr[Arraylength] > tmp)
            return arr[Arraylength];
```

Indexes start at 0, so you will be out of bound for an array with 5 elements `[1,2,3,4,5]` indexes: `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a plain loop.  Java doesn't do recursion particularly well.

```
public static int maximum(int[] arr) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i : arr) if (i > max) max = i;
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Actually m new in programming, and i was interviewed with recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
System.out.println("In the array entered, the larget value is "+ maximum(myArray,arraySize) + ".");
```

you are passing the arraysize where in **maximum** method you are returning **arr[Arraylength]** which giving ArrayIndexOutOfBound so change either in calling **maximum(yArray,arraySize-1)** or **return arr[Arraylength-1]** statement.